# Smoother CSS3 Christmas animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Was wondering how to get smooth animation like this http://codepen.io/ndeniche/pen/LtvjK

```
#canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 780px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I created something similar, but my animation is so laggy, as you can see it here 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJNzYa

```
#content {
  max-width: 760px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background: radial-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #d4d4d4 70%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yours looks identical to the other example on my machine in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

First let me say that CSS animation performance is not something you can throw a line of code at to improve. Being client side, everyone has difference hardware so there is sort of a fine line at times on what is too much.

I suggest using Chrome devtools to help see what is making the browser struggle to achieve those silky smooth 60fps animations. Addy Osmani has a great write up on [how to use Chrome devtools to improve paint performance](http://addyosmani.com/blog/devtools-visually-re-engineering-css-for-faster-paint-times/)

One thing I noticed though right away is that you are using `transform:translateZ(0);` to force hardware acceleration. While this is great way to improve performance, you have it set on `*` Depending on the amount of stuff in the DOM, you can burn up a lot of the browsers resources doing this. Also, you have a `filter:blur(3px)`, while the other pen has a `filter:blur(1px)`. This 2px difference is tremendous for the amount of falling snowflakes and can be attributing to the jank as well.  :)

If you want to go more in depth on the subject, check out [High Performance Animations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) by Paul Lewis and Paul Irish.